# Swift error "Hashbang line is allowed only in the main file"

Tags: swift, xcode, command-line-interface

I wish to create an interpreted Swift command-line utility. Thus, in Xcode 13.1, I create a new project, and use the template "Command Line Tool". This results in an empty project with a single file, called main.swift.

I want to distribute this command-line utility as a single file, so having the "main.swift" name isn't useful. I rename it to `MyCommandlineProject.swift`, then add the hashbang line on top, and add code that marks it as being the main file. The contents now look as follows:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

@main
struct CLI {
    static func main() {
        print("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Despite the `@main` annotation, I still get the following compiler error:

```
Hashbang line is allowed only in the main file
```

Why?

Comment: You are trying to use a Xcode command line project which needs to compile to a binary, there you can only use a hashbang on the main.swift . Which is how Xcode handles hashbangs. You can also use Swift for scripting without Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just writing a script you don't need any of that @main stuff. @main is really only for when you have multiple files that you need to compile into an executable.

For a script, like you are writing, you can just add top level functions and they will get called just as if you were writing in a playground.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

print("Hello, World!")
```

You can execute the script with:

```
chmod 744 scriptName.swift
./scriptName.swift
```

Or

```
swift scriptName.swift
```

Now if you have multiple files, let's call them First.swift:

```
import Foundation

@main enum First {
    static func main() {
        print("First.main")
        Second.execute()
    }
}
```

And Second.swift:

```
import Foundation

enum Second {
    static func execute() { print("Second.execute") }
}
```

You have to prefix your entry point with `@main` like we did for `First`. You also have to give it a static `main()` method.

First you have to compile:

```
swiftc -o awesome First.swift Second.swift
```

Then to run:

```
./awesome
```

Comment: "For a script, like you are writing, you can just add top level functions and they will get called just as if you were writing in a playground." Inside Xcode, that's not entirely true. I'm looking for the case of creating an empty command line project, and renaming the main.swift file, then trying to compile it without an error.